CallKit invokes CXEndCallAction after starting the call, resulting in hangup on Simulator
I am using Xcode Version 15.3 (15E204a) and different versions of Simulator runtimes (17.x, 16.x, 15.0)
The app makes outgoing calls and can respond to incoming calls, works fine on real devices, but running on simulator started having problems after latest updates.
After starting the call, ~2s pass before a hangup occurs. In the Console logs I see that CXEndCallAction was invoked by CallKit and the last suspicious log before invoking the CXEndCallAction is:
callservicesd Disconnecting call because there wont be a UI to host the call: <CSDProviderCall 0x107054300 type=PhoneNumber, value=sdsddsdds, stat=Sending tStat=0, model=<TUCallModel 0x103f661e0 hold=1 grp=1 ungrp=1> ...

Analysing the Console logs I can see that the CXStartCallAction was invoked and later fulfilled.
I tried enabling VoIP setting in the project, event though the app was functional without it before the updates, but to no avail.
This problem happens always on iOS 17.x, sometimes on 16.x, and never on 15.x.
Has someone experienced similar issues or has an idea for a fix/workaround?
I tried delaying the actions and dispatching them on separate threads.
I also tried enabling VoIP capabilities in project .info settings:
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>

